# How to integrate python paho-mqtt with job queue?

Tags: python, paho

I am writing application for IoT project that needs to use Python and subscribes for some topic. Upon message received I need to add new job to queue along with respective priority which will then be executed according to that priority. The issue is that there can be a lot of messages in the same time sometimes, and I need to prioritize them and execute them upon previous is finished.

The problem is that I can't integrate it both. Queue example I am using

```
import Queue

class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, priority, description):
        self.priority = priority
        self.description = description
        print 'New job:', description
        return
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)

q = Queue.PriorityQueue()

q.put( Job(3, 'Mid-level job') )
q.put( Job(10, 'Low-level job') )
q.put( Job(1, 'Important job') )

while not q.empty():
    next_job = q.get()
    print 'Processing job:', next_job.description
```

The problem is where to put the bottom part

```
while not q.empty():
        next_job = q.get()
        print 'Processing job:', next_job.description
```

inside MQTT-paho structure

I have this

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import datetime
import json
from time import sleep

import Queue

class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, priority, description):
        self.priority = priority
        self.description = description
        print 'New job:', description
        return
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)

q = Queue.PriorityQueue()

from pprint import pprint

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc): 
    client.subscribe("mytopic")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    #here I had the job to queqe for example
    q.put( Job(1, 'Important job') )

#where should I call the queue

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("host", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

I tried adding it to on_message, but I get this error

```
File "myfile.py", line 136, in <module>
    client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using: `client.loop_start()` instead of `client.loop_forever()`

`client.loop_forever()` sometimes block the execution of program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another thread to handle `client.loop_forever()`.